# Почему не получается подружить php и Arduino?

Tags: php, arduino

Нужно что бы когда вызван php загоралась лампочка! 
Код PHP:

```
<?
  $fp =fopen("com3", "w");
  fwrite($fp, chr(50));
  fclose($fp);
?>
```

Скетч:

```
int ledPin = 13;
int usbnumber = 0;

void setup() {
pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() { // основной цикл
if (Serial.available() > 
0) {
 usbnumber = Serial.read();
}
if (usbnumber > 
0) { 
if (usbnumber == '1'){
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  delay(300);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  delay(300);
}

usbnumber = 0;
 }
}
```

Comment: А настройка параметров порта со стороны PHP где?

Comment: Как реализовать?

Comment: В душе не знаю как это в PHP, да еще и на непонятной ОС :-) Но точно знаю что параметры порта должны совпадать

Answer (score 0):

Нужно настроить аттрибуты COM-порта. Например, так:

```
<?php

$fd = dio_open('/dev/ttyS0', O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);

dio_fcntl($fd, F_SETFL, O_SYNC);

dio_tcsetattr($fd, array(
  'baud' => 9600,
  'bits' => 8,
  'stop'  => 1,
  'parity' => 0
)); 

while (1) {

  $data = dio_read($fd, 256);

  if ($data) {
      echo $data;
  }
} 

?>
```

Пример взят [отсюда](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dio-tcsetattr.php).